# Add two arrays with holes to fill the holes in the other array

Tags: python, numpy

I have scans of data from Africa that are from the same day at different times. I'd like to consolidate the data into one one array. How can I do that?

np.add(x,y, where=some possbile function?)

Edit: In case it's unclear. I would like to have on image with all of the yellow from the two images.

[image: Scan]

Comment: It's not clear how you want to consolidate the data.  For example, do you want to stack the data horizontally, or vertically or interlace the data (i.e. alternating rows between the two data sets)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. You can use another array in the np.where() function. So the data here is split up in *am* and *pm* passes

```
both = np.where(data_am < 0, data_pm ,data_am)
combined = np.where(both < 0, 0 ,both)
```

[image: Combined data]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `np.concatenate((x,y),axis=1)` to consolidate data into one array.

axis=1 for column-wise concatenation and axis=0 for row-wise concatenation

Example with column-wise

```
x = np.array(([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]))
y = np.array(([10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]))
result = np.concatenate((x,y),axis=1)
```

Result

```
[[ 1  2  3 10 11 12]
 [ 4  5  6 13 14 15]
 [ 7  8  9 16 17 18]]
```

Example with row-wise

```
x = np.array(([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]))
y = np.array(([10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]))
result = np.concatenate((x,y),axis=0)
```

Result

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]
 [13 14 15]
 [16 17 18]]
```

Comment: I would like a 2x2 array out put where the values from yellow fill in the cooresponding values if they are blue in the other.

Comment: Any example input?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you have one array with values and you want to put the other data in the same array below? Maybe [np.vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) is the code you are looking for? The relevant part would be:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
>>> np.vstack((a,b))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: No. I would like a 2x2 array out put where the values from yellow fill in the cooresponding values if they are blue in the other.